# FingerJetFXOSE Cygwin compilation error

Tags: c++, gcc

Can someone help me, Im having problem in compiling FingerJetFXOSE in Cygwin 32
gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC)

I used the following command:

```
$ make -f Makefile
make -C src/libFRFXLL
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/src/FingerJetFXOSE-master/src/libFRFXLL'
make -C src/libFRFXLL
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/src/FingerJetFXOSE-    master/src/libFRFXLL/src/libFRFXLL'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/src/FingerJetFXOSE-master/src/libFRFXLL/src/libFRFXLL'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/src/FingerJetFXOSE-master/src/libFRFXLL'
make -C src/libfjfx
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/src/FingerJetFXOSE-master/src/libfjfx'
g++ -O2  -Wl,--strip-all -I../../include -I../libFRFXLL/include -fno-    exceptions-fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -shared -nodefaultlibs -Wl,--version-script
```

I got this error at the end:

```
../libFRFXLL/lib/libFRFXLL.a(FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.o):FRFXLLCreat                                                                                                                
eFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.cpp:(.text$_ZN14FingerJetFxOSE15FpRecEngineImpl20Featu                                                                                                                
reExtractionObjINS0_8Embedded24FeatureExtractionInPlaceEE16CreateFeatureSetIhEEi                                                                                                                
PT_jjjjjPPv[__ZN14FingerJetFxOSE15FpRecEngineImpl20FeatureExtractionObjINS0_8Emb                                                                                                                
edded24FeatureExtractionInPlaceEE16CreateFeatureSetIhEEiPT_jjjjjPPv]+0x159c): un                                                                                                                
defined reference to `memmove'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:62: ../../lib/libfjfx.so.5.2.0] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/usr/FingerJetFXOSE-master/src/libfjfx'
make: *** [Makefile:50: src/libfjfx] Error 2
```

Thanks

Comment: The actual error is before these lines. `make` should also print the command which led to this error. Please include this information.

Comment: Just edit your post to add a few more lines of the messages from `make` before those you shared so far.

Comment: Can you post a few more lines above the error? In particular, the line which runs a command like `gcc`, `g++`, or `ld`? Thanks.

Comment: Is that information you need Sir?

Comment: I meant a few lines from the end, before the actual error message.  There should be an invocation of `gcc`, `g++`, `ld` which fails. I want to know how it looks like. It could span multiple lines.

Comment: thats all I got Sir, after i compile it, Im new in Biometrics and i just want to use FingerJetFXOSE SDK as my template extractor, and if the test is successfully Im going to port it in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the makefiles for the FingerJetFXOSE project here:

- https://github.com/FingerJetFXOSE/FingerJetFXOSE

The makefiles do not support Cygwin.  The README says that Windows is supported, but I suspect they mean a Visual-Studio-based build after a manual source import.

I think you either have to compile on GNU/Linux, or compile this code without the upstream makefiles.

Comment: I see, ill take a look and get back with the result sir. thanks